# How to Install Perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I've to install Perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 as per my requirement. When I download and install the package I get the following errors,

```
cc -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -o miniperl \
          gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o xsutils.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o  \
        miniperlmain.o opmini.o perlmini.o 
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_pow':
pp.c:(.text+0x2daf): undefined reference to `pow'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_modulo':
pp.c:(.text+0x39ee): undefined reference to `floor'
pp.c:(.text+0x3a21): undefined reference to `floor'
pp.c:(.text+0x3d94): undefined reference to `fmod'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_atan2':
pp.c:(.text+0x8a05): undefined reference to `atan2'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_sin':
pp.c:(.text+0x8ba2): undefined reference to `sin'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_int':
pp.c:(.text+0x9061): undefined reference to `floor'
pp.c:(.text+0x90d1): undefined reference to `ceil'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x120): undefined reference to `cos'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x128): undefined reference to `sin'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x130): undefined reference to `sin'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x138): undefined reference to `exp'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x140): undefined reference to `log'
pp.o:(.rodata+0x148): undefined reference to `sqrt'
pp_pack.o: In function `S_pack_rec':
pp_pack.c:(.text+0x72b3): undefined reference to `floor'
pp_pack.c:(.text+0x72d6): undefined reference to `floor'
pp_pack.c:(.text+0x7303): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [miniperl] Error 1
```

I tried including math library `<math.h>` in the file **pp.c** but of no use. Is there anything more I need to do?

Also please tell me whether there is a tool that converts Perl 5.10.1 Script compatible with Perl 5.18.2 as I get backward compatibility warnings when I compile with 5.18.2.

Comment: Why do you need an old version of perl? There should be precompiled packages available. And if not - what are you doing to build your new perl? Looks like you're trying to compile with `cc` - do you have `gcc` installed?

Comment: https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv

Comment: @Sobrique Yes I do have some precompiled packages. To execute them I need the older version of Perl... The C compilation is a part of the installation

Comment: The error messages are from the linker, not from the compiler. You should get away by placing a `-lm` at the *end* of all compilation lines.

Comment: Also: installation questions are not something that I'd expect on SO and you are not supposed to ask more than one question in one.

Comment: How can I do that in between installation of Perl? I run commands to install Perl. In the middle there exists this file which is throwing these errors

Comment: `math.h` is not a library, it is a header.  `#include`-ing the header does not help the linker find the library.

Comment: Landed here searching through Google. I eventually solved thanks to the suggestion by @JensGustedt: I opened the Makefile, located a line "libs = " and  added -lm at it, turning it into "libs = -lm". The same can be obtained passing "-A append:libs=-lm" to Configure --Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/), a program that manages Perl installations.

1. Install it using `apt-get install perlbrew` as root
2. Initialize it by running `perlbrew init`
3. Add `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to your `.bashrc` and start a new shell.
4. Install perl 5.10 using `perlbrew install perl-5.10.1`
5. You can now use `perlbrew use` to change the Perl for the current shell, or `perlbrew switch` to change the Perl globally.

If you only need one Perl and want to avoid the complexity of `perlbrew`, you can try [perl-build](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl-build).

Comment: Equivalently, you could probably add a sufficiently old Ubuntu (or, gasp, Debian) package source to Apt, and install the once-standard precompiled binary. Old source can be tricky to build because the toolchain has also changed. (Putting `-lm` last used to be optional, for example.)

Comment: Perlbrew also fails to make perl 5.10.1 on newer Ubuntus (18.04).

Answer (score 2):

Tried many things and this worked for me finally :)

Step 1: find your lib path which has all `libm*` files

In most systems it was under `/usr/lib64`. Search for the same in your machine

```
system:/usr/lib64$ ls libm*
libm.a         libmcheck.a     libmenuw.so.5    libmpc.so.3.0.0    libmpfr.so.4  libmpx.so.0.0.0      libm.so         libmvec.a
libmagic.so.1      libmenu.so.5    libmenuw.so.5.9  libmpdec.so.2      libmpfr.so.4.1.4  libmpxwrappers.so.0      libmspack.so.0      libmvec_nonshared.a
libmagic.so.1.0.0  libmenu.so.5.9  libmpc.so.3      libmpdec.so.2.4.2  libmpx.so.0   libmpxwrappers.so.0.0.0  libmspack.so.0.1.0  libmvec.so
```

Step 2: Use the path with `glibpth` option while doing configure

```
./Configure -des -Dglibpth='/lib/lib64 /usr/lib64'
```

or I see some forums suggested `plibpth`

```
./Configure -des -Dplibpth='/lib/lib64 /usr/lib64' -Dglibpth='/lib/lib64 /usr/lib64' -Dlibpth='/lib/lib64 /usr/lib64'
```